# Landing pages as a percent of total pages

Tags: looker-studio

(Data Studio Report - Single source of data: GAnalytics)

A website has, say:

- 200 pages receiving views.
- 66 pages receiving all entrances, all sources (Landing Pages).

In data studio, I've created scorecards for both of the above stats.
I now want to create a pie which visually expresses the KPI: "30% of pages are landing pages".

I'm relatively new to Data Studio and think I'm struggling with dimensions v metrics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### As a Scorecard...

I've been able to achieve this as a scorecard (and it was correct), so here's the solution I found:

Create a **calculated field** with the *formula*:

- `COUNT_DISTINCT(Landing Page) / COUNT_DISTINCT(Page)`

Add this new calculated metric to a scorecard metric slot, it'll automatically chose percentage to express the result.

**Note:** The above is using a single data source: Google Analytics (GA).

*** I'll update re the pie chart....

---

(I've not achieved this with Blended Data - my next quest)